# The Kendo UI directives require jQuery to be available before AngularJS. Please include jquery before angular in the document

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, angular-ui-router, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I have a Mvc with angular application.

There are two layout files :
Loginlayout: - Default layout
MasterLayout:

When click the Movie button , call the Movie Controller and Movie action.

```
    public ActionResult Movie()
    {

        return View();
    }
```

Its using mainlayout file:

In Mainlayout file i have mentioned

```
<script src="
            https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.714/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.1/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

In page refresh , scripts get orderly loaded,
while click the movie button. i am getting this error.

I have attached screenshot below:

[image][image]

[image]
while click the Movie button scripts order
Error getting when click the Movie button
When Page refresh scripts loaded

Comment: did fou found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same issue, i was loading jquery twice,
for other possible answers [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611672/the-kendo-ui-directives-require-jquery-to-be-available-before-angularjs-with-ken/42602418#42602418)