# kendo grid loaded before dom is ready in partial views in mvc with angular routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

When full page refresh scripts ordered properly,application works fine. Problem when load the partial view , html markup loaded first,after that scripts gets loaded , so its saying error.

**Error**: **kendo requires jquery.**

How to avoid this .

markup in partial view is

## Partners

```
<div id="Grid" class="hrScrollOut" kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions" k-rebind="gridOptionsPes">
```

Script order changing when navigate the routing with events.

Kendo load before Jquery. In page Refresh, Scripts ordered is correct.

Script order is

Answer (score 0):

If you use "_Layout.cshtml" import the JQuery file and Kendo JS in it. Where are you referring the JS file for Kendo

Comment: check this , i have added jquery before angular , element loaded before scripts. more:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38507535/the-kendo-ui-directives-require-jquery-to-be-available-before-angularjs-please